# Gwt Maven multimodule. How to configure dependencies to put Request Factory Proxies in shared module?

Tags: java, xml, maven, gwt, multi-module

Gwt Project consist of 3 parts: `client`, `shared` and `server`.

I would like to create that structure with maven, but for each part of gwt app I would like to have separate module.

So I have multimodule maven project. It consist of 4 modules:

1. Parent module
2. Web module
3. Shared module
4. Server module

I would like to put `Request Factory Proxies` interfaces in `shared` module. How can I do this?

**My current pom.xml configuration do not allow me that. I am getting  errors, that:**

`Classes from server module cannot be resolved to a type`

---

Here is my configuration:

---

**1. Parent module** dosen't have any classes or GWT configurations.
It have only `pom.xml`. It agregate rest of modules. Here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>shared</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
    </build>
</project>
```

**2. Web module** have `pom.xml` and `gwt.xml` configuration.
The xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<module rename-to='parent'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.RequestFactory' />

    <!-- Application module inherits -->
    <inherits name="pl.derp.shared" />
    <inherits name="pl.derp.server" />

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='pl.derp.web.Parent2' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='web' />
</module>
```

And `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
            <artifactId>server</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    </build>
</project>
```

**3. Shared module** have `pom.xml` and `gwt.xml` configuration.
The xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<module rename-to='shared'>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

    <source path="web"/>
    <source path="shared"/>
</module>
```

And `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
        <build>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**4. Server module** have `pom.xml` and `gwt.xml` configuration.
The xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<module rename-to='server'>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

    <inherits name="pl.derp.shared"/>

    <source path="server"/>
</module>
```

And `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please help me.

---

Edit

New maven dependencies propositions:

parent module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>mrf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <modules>
    <module>mrf-domain</module>
    <module>mrf-server</module>
    <module>mrf-shared</module>
    <module>mrf-client</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <mavenVersion>3.0</mavenVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir</launcherDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-rc-2</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <sourceLevel>1.7</sourceLevel>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

domain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mrf-domain</artifactId>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mrf-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mrf-shared</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <id>requestfactory-validation-tool</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>java</executable>
              <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-Dverbose=true</argument>
                <argument>-cp</argument>
                <classpath />
                <argument>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ValidationTool</argument>
                <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                <argument>pl.AppFactory</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.2,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <!-- XXX: We want to exclude mrf-client from 'env-dev' profile, Maven forces us to make a 'env-prod' profile -->
      <id>env-prod</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>mrf-client</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <type>war</type>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                  <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
                    <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${basedir}/../target/gwt/launcherDir/</resourcesAsCSV>
                  </baseResource>
                  <extraClasspath>${basedir}/../mrf-shared/target/classes/</extraClasspath>
                  <extraClasspath>${basedir}/../mrf-domain/target/classes/</extraClasspath>
                </webApp>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <addWarDependenciesInClassloader>false</addWarDependenciesInClassloader>
                <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/tomcatconf/context.xml</contextFile>
                <path>/</path>
                <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <addWarDependenciesInClassloader>false</addWarDependenciesInClassloader>
                <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/tomcatconf/context.xml</contextFile>
                <path>/</path>
                <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

shared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mrf-shared</artifactId>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mrf-domain</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-client</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>mrf-client</artifactId>
  <packaging>gwt-app</packaging>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mrf-shared</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>mrf-shared</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>pl.App</moduleName>
          <moduleShortName>mrf</moduleShortName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Unfortunately, when I am trying to use in `proxy` class:
`@ProxyFor(pl.domain.GreetingResponse2.class)`

I am getting an error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mrf ............................................... SUCCESS [0.106s]
[INFO] mrf-domain ........................................ SUCCESS [0.893s]
[INFO] mrf-shared ........................................ SUCCESS [0.277s]
[INFO] mrf-client ........................................ SUCCESS [6.519s]
[INFO] mrf-server ........................................ FAILURE [0.599s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.824s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 05 13:33:27 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/311M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (requestfactory-validation-tool) on project mrf-server: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (requestfactory-validation-tool) on project mrf-server: Command execution failed.
```

When instead I use: `@ProxyForName("pl.server.GreetingResponse")`, it's compile fine. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have `shared` (and `client`) depend on `server` so you can reference server-side classes from `@ProxyFor` and `@Service`; but then you risk referencing server-side classes from shared and client-side code and only notice it when using the GWT compiler or devmode (i.e. late), and therefore having absolutely no benefit in using a multi-module Maven project.

Or you can use `@ProxyForName` and `@ServiceName` which loosens the dependency from `shared` on `server` by making it implicit; that way `client` only depends on `shared` without any dependency on `server`.
You can see an example of that approach in the `modular-requestfactory` Maven archetype at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

---

BTW, I consider a `server`+`shared`+`client` trio to be a single "unit" (only artificially split in 3 tiers to accomodate Maven limitations wrt dependency scopes and the likes), and I simply make them share a common root package (with or without `server`, `shared` and `client` subpackages). That way I can have a single `*.gwt.xml` in the `client` module bringing bothe client and shared files in GWT's "source path"; and the `shared` module can have zero dependency on GWT (only a `provided` dependency on `requestfactory-client` or `requestfactory-server`; `client` will use `gwt-user` instead, and `server` will use `requestfactory-server` or `gwt-servlets`).

Comment: I will dive into Yours archetypes. Seems to be much cleaner than my.

Comment: Hey. I see that You have `@ProxyForName` string class declaration in [request factory project in `Proxy` class.](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/blob/master/modular-requestfactory/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/__rootArtifactId__-shared/src/main/java/GreetingResponseProxy.java)  I am trying to rewrite this with type safe class declaration like: `@ProxyFor(value = GreetingResponse.class)`, but I am failling, can You help?

Comment: You could possibly split `server` in two: one part with services and domain objects that `shared` could depend on with `<optional>true</optional>` or `<scope>provided</scope>` (so that `client` doesn't inherit it; you could additionally explicitly exclude the transitive dependency in `client`); the other part that depends on the first one and on `shared`, to build the webapp. You'd then have `webapp` depends on `shared`, `client` (compiled to JS) and `server`; `shared` depends on `server`, `client` depends on `shared` but **not** `server`.

Comment: Hey. I've tried to follow Your sugestion. Unfortunatelly I have problem with request factory validation tool, as I supose? Please look again on my post. I've updated my new poms. Thanks.

Comment: If you use exclusively `@ProxyFor` and `@Service` (or more generally if you have the "domain" classes available at build-time of the proxy classes), then you can use the annotation processor in `shared` (`requestfactory-apt` dependency, must be present in compile classpath, absent at runtime: use `provided` scope or set as `optional`) instead of the validation tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect the maven structure.
In the directory that has the pom of each module you have to have the directory /src in which you have to save the sources.

Maven looks for this directory when building a module.
Here you can read more about this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

But I would not recommend you to change the standard structure of a GWT application.

Think of the developers that will want to work further on your code. They will expect the standard and it will be hard for them to understand the structure at first.